# creating google drive client program

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to create a desktop app based on java which could upload, download and share files from google drive.
Actually I am creating a email client and file sharing client application. I want to let my users to share their files using frontend of my java app. I also want to store the gmail attachments to google drive automatically in this app.

Comment: Do you have a specific question? So far, you've just stated your (fairly broad in scope) requirements.

Comment: where is the question here?

Comment: Specifically can I integrate Google drive with my java desktop app? And if yes what should I do for that..?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Java quickstart in the Google Drive SDK documentation to learn how write a command-line Java app that uploads files to Google Drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

Comment: thank you claudio.. 
I am done with quickstart and i have runned the sample code..
my main intention is to share the file which i'm not getting..
could you help me on this..??

Comment: Check this page for more details about sharing: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing